# onclick events for highstock rangeselecor and width is not applying

Tags: highcharts

I have an issue with x-axis values from the rangeselector in Highstock If I select 1d x-axis values should be hourly basis like 00.00 ,01.00,02.00....23.00. If I select 1w x-axis values should be jan-1,jan-2,jan-3 If I select 1m x-axis values are jan-1, jan-2 with interval of one week.Please find the below fiddle file of my code.

http://jsfiddle.net/t6uYV/

```
                 buttons[1].on('click', function (e) {
                    console.debug("hello onclick of the button ");
                        reset_all_buttons();
                        chart.rangeSelector.buttons[1].setState(2);


                        chart.xAxis[0].setTitle({
                            title: {
                                text: 'Date/time',
                                type: "datetime",
                                tickInterval : 24 * 3600 * 1000,
                                dateTimeLabelFormats: {
                                    day: '%b %d'
                                },
                                labels: {
                                    formatter: function() {
                                        return Highcharts.dateFormat('%b %d', this.value);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        });

                        chart.setSize(900,600,false);

                        chart.addSeries({
                            name : 'Energy Consumption',
                            id   : 'EnergyConsumption_data',
                            yAxis: 1,
                            data : [[Date.UTC(2013,05,20),12],[Date.UTC(2013,05,21),14],[Date.UTC(2013,05,22),16],[Date.UTC(2013,05,23),22],[Date.UTC(2013,05,24),11],[Date.UTC(2013,05,25),10],[Date.UTC(2013,05,26),14]],
                            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
                        }); 
                        chart.addSeries({
                            name : 'OutDoor Temperature',
                            id   : 'OutDoorTemperature_data',
                            data : [[Date.UTC(2013,05,20),24],[Date.UTC(2013,05,21),14],[Date.UTC(2013,05,22),16],[Date.UTC(2013,05,23),22],[Date.UTC(2013,05,24),11],[Date.UTC(2013,05,25),10],[Date.UTC(2013,05,26),14]],
                            pointInterval: 24 * 3600 * 1000
                        });

                    });
```

width is not applying when click any of the rangeselector value.

Please provide me the solution for this . Struggling for this last one week.

Thanks in Advance,

Mahidhar

Answer (score 0):

It is related with tickInterval, so you need to use setting tickInterval dynamically. To achieve this, you should use tickPositioner http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#xAxis.tickPositioner

Comment: I solved x-axis label issue by using tickinterval like below  chart.xAxis[0].update({tickInterval : 1 * 24 * 3600 * 1000})